# Function signature changes for forward-compatible interfaces

Tags: c, macros, libraries

Is there a common practice how to extend a C API while staying forward compatible?

Suppose I want to provide a function foo in a c library:

```
foo(int value);
```

Now in a later version I would like to extend foo to allow another parameter.

```
foo(int value, const char *description_may_be_NULL);
```

To ensure forward-compatibility I would have to name the new one differently, e.g. `foo2`.

Would it be clever to provide a macro such that:

```
#define MYLIB_API 2
#include <mylib.h>
/* the header will #define foo foo2 */
```

That would avoid using nasty names in practice.

Are there any common practices how to handle the conflicting forward compatibility and elegant code for future versions? Any examples of how popular C APIs have handled that in the past would be appreciated.

Edit: Unfortunately I didn't clearly mention this: The `foo(int)` signature is already set, so introducing varargs/struct parameters would also be an incompatible API change. It is not actually probable that many functions will change over time, but some will eventually. Paying ahead for all functions with an uncommon signature seems a high price to me.

Comment: The UNIX & Linux kernel (actually C library interface) tend to do exactly what you suggest, provide a new updated function as `foo2`.  Sometimes MACRO games are played, so as to 'transparently' provide LARGEFILE support.  I should just accept & document the new function, unless you are in position to globally update all function calls to your library function and all header files.  Playing macro games, so that `foo()` is really `foo2()` is liable to confuse or cause confusion one day, when the `.h` file isn't used as you expect.

Comment: open(2), was extended to take a file mode Version 6 UNIX just had creat(2) and open(2) for existing files only.  The flag O_CREAT was added to the call in compatible way, so sometimes with flags you can get away with extensions.  This talk has excellent discussion of issues resulting from rushed ABI design and need for avoiding `looseness` in extensible interface to maintain ability to make compatible changes - see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlozCt8WfnU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a pointer to a structure...

```
typedef struct
{
    int value;
} typeStructure;

void foo(const typeStructure * const pTypeStructure);
```

Should `typeStructure` be expanded, older versions of `foo` will simply ignore new fields.

Comment: Include a *version* in this struct, and it is the most sensible option by far.  

Now there is a well defined function signature.  Version tells you which fields actually exist (ie: don't de-reference garbage fields from unset struct values!).  And even where fields exist across multiple versions, the version number tells you what those fields are supposed to mean.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest solution. However it does complicate function signatures and calls that may or may not be extended in the future. This is not an acceptable default for a library unless you have a specific strong expectation of future extensions. It proves that in C there is no good solution for this issue.

Comment: @Zulan `However it does complicate function signatures and calls that may or may not be extended in the future.` If you mean the signature of `foo` cannot change to remain backward compatible, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: @FiddlingBits my Understanding is that the signature doesn't _need_ to be changed to and backward compatibility can be implemented using some _version_ flag or reserved padding in the struct. What I meant was that if I have 50 API call and probably one or two will change in the future, then I would not design all 50 signatures to take a struct instead of the usual parameters.

Comment: @Zulan Sounds like an interesting follow up question.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a variable function:

```
void foo(int arg, ...);
```

In the first implementation, you just consume the first argument. In future versions (perhaps conditional on `arg` having a certain value), you can use `va_arg` to get access to further arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foo();`.
no argument inside parenthesis means unspecified number of arguments and you can call it with any number of parameters.

Other way is `va_args` variable argument function like `printf()`, or variadic macro which will call your `foo`

`#define FOO(...) foo(__VA_ARGS_)`

Comment: You should point out the drawbacks and lack of error checking, through following this suggestion.